# Adding a package to the ROS distro with third party dependencies

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, bloom-release, xmlrpc, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite new to the ROS packaging stuff so please advise me if I am heading in the wrong direction. I do want to add the ROS driver of our 3D Time of Flight cameras to the ROS distribution. At the moment I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic. The ROS node for the cameras is hosted here: https://github.com/lovepark/ifm3d-ros this node depends on the Open Source library [ifm3d library](https://github.com/lovepark/ifm3d). To add the [ifm3d library](https://github.com/lovepark/ifm3d) I followed the [Bloom Releasing a Third Party Package](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseThirdParty) tutorial. Due to the fact that the [ifm3d library](https://github.com/lovepark/ifm3d) depends on multiple packages I am struggling with the following dependencies at the moment:

- libgoogle-glog-dev (Ubuntu) [Google logging module](https://github.com/google/glog)
- libxmlrpc-c++8-dev (Ubuntu) [XML-RPC for C and C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/)

Those dependencies are not available in the [rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml) and therefore I do get the following error message when running `git-bloom-release kinetic`

```
Could not resolve rosdep key 'glog'
Failed to resolve glog on ubuntu:xenial with: Error running generator: Failed to resolve rosdep key 'glog', aborting.
glog is depended on by these packages: ['ifm3d-core']
<== Failed
Could not resolve rosdep key 'xmlrpc-c++'
Failed to resolve xmlrpc-c++ on ubuntu:xenial with: Error running generator: Failed to resolve rosdep key 'xmlrpc-c++', aborting.
xmlrpc-c++ is depended on by these packages: ['ifm3d-core']
<== Failed
Some of the dependencies for packages in this repository could not be resolved by rosdep.
You can try to address the issues which appear above and try again if you wish.
Would you like to try again? [Y/n]? n
User aborted after rosdep keys were not resolved.
<== The following generator action reported that it is missing one or more
    rosdep keys, but that the key exists in other platforms:
'['/usr/bin/git-bloom-generate', '-y', 'rosdebian', '--prefix', 'release/kinetic', 'kinetic', '-i', '1', '--os-name', 'ubuntu']'
```

As far I do understand the way to proceed is by adding those dependencies to [rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml) which will provide `rosdep` the ability to resolve all the dependencies on all supported platforms. Is there a recommended way to check all the package names for all *inux Platforms or is is legal to add the dependency graph only for my usecase which is tested by me?

I am sure I've mixed up a lot, so please be kind and advise me how to proceed in a correct way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298691/adding-a-package-to-the-ros-distro-with-third-party-dependencies/) by [christian.ege](https://answers.ros.org/users/36665/christian.ege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-26**:
Isn't `libgoogle-glog-dev` already present in `rosdep`? The key is [libgoogle-glog-dev](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/b47c91cb005dd268b212fd1051a33330d19d4541/rosdep/base.yaml#L1884-L1888), not `glog`.

**Comment by [christian.ege](https://answers.ros.org/users/36665/christian.ege/) on 2018-07-26**:
@gvdhoorn  you are totally right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: Welcome, and thanks for making those packages available as binaries! The documentation on how to contribute a new rosdep rule is here:

http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html

You are correct in that the dependencies need to be added to `base.yaml`. And I believe an effort should be made to add the dependencies for all supported platforms. That way, binaries for the ifm3d library will be built for all supported platforms as well!

Unfortunately I don't have any advice on the best way to find all those package names, except check on the online package listings for all the distros.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christian.ege](https://answers.ros.org/users/36665/christian.ege/) on 2018-07-26**:
In the [contributer guideline](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#rosdep-rules-contributions) there is also some help provided